# Quick MySQL Trigger Update

Tags: mysql

I need to change this trigger to point to the column that just got updated so what do I change NEW.song_id to?? Thanks!

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `ratings_update`//
CREATE TRIGGER `ratings_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `ratings2`
FOR EACH ROW update SONGS set
rating_sum = rating_sum + NEW.rating,
rating = rating_sum / rating_count
where id = NEW.song_id
//
```

EDIT vvv

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `ratings_upd`//
CREATE TRIGGER `ratings_upd` AFTER UPDATE ON `ratings2`
FOR EACH ROW update SONGS set
rating_sum = rating_sum + NEW.rating - OLD.rating,
rating_count = rating_count,
rating = rating_sum / rating_count
where id = NEW.song_id
//
```

This is what I came up with for my trigger but it is throwing me this error when I run it..

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '// CREATE TRIGGER `ratings_upd` AFTER UPDATE ON `ratings2` FOR EACH ROW update ' at line 1

Comment: What do you mean by 'point to the column that just got updated'? `NEW` references the new record after the update, which seems to be what you're asking about, so I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: Okay I understand, but this is if somebody updates their previous rating so is their a way I access their old rating that got updated so I can calculate rating_sum = rating_sum - OLD.rating + NEW.rating?? Thanks.

Comment: Well, it seems like you answered your own question. Won't `rating_sum = rating_sum - OLD.rating + NEW.rating` do what you want?

Comment: If that's valid syntax.. I didn't know if OLD.rating was the actual syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OLD` accesses values before the update, and `NEW` accesses values after the update.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html:

> You can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases OLD and NEW. OLD.col_name refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted. NEW.col_name refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, can you check my EDIT and see if you know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: @NickNelson Are you setting your delimiter to //? You don't really need to change the delimiter for that code anyway, try changing the // to ;.

Comment: I just removed the drop if exists portion, thanks for your help its working exactly how I want it to now