# Trouble with creating simple MySQL Trigger on Update

Tags: php, mysql, database, triggers

(Edit: Apologies for the funky formatting. SO was not having my code formatted.)

I feel dumb, but i've been racking my brain for this for longer then I like to admit.

I need a trigger that, when any update to menu_button is made, it updates a field in `soa_config`  to the datetime the update was made (`parameterValue` is a `Varchar`). I've tried doing it as simple as setting `parameterValue='1'`, no dice either. Running the update by itself, and the trigger, sans everything, and both work. It's the combination of the two that makes it hard. I get the error

`"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1".`

```
    delimiter |
    CREATE TRIGGER imatrigger AFTER UPDATE on `menu_button`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    UPDATE soa_config 
    SET parameter_value = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
    WHERE parameter_name = last_menu_update_itme

    END
    |
    delimiter ;
```

I've looked at:
[Quick MySQL Trigger Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266051/quick-mysql-trigger-update)

[Trouble in creating Trigger in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348901/trouble-in-creating-trigger-in-mysql)

[MYSQL trigger trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416983/mysql-trigger-trouble)

[sql creating a trigger on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485302/sql-creating-a-trigger-on-update)

and more googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a statement delimiter after the `WHERE` clause and before the `END` statement

i.e. you should have a semi-colon here: `WHERE parameter_name = last_menu_update_itme;` <----

Comment: Son of a polecat, that was it. Thanks!